# Adding max fee c#

Tags: c#, arrays, max

i need to add a max fee to this and confused on how to do it, i have added 
const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00M; to the code and tried some different ways but they didnt work, such as ifs and else if :( help please

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] hours = new int[31];
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5M;
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00M;
        decimal pay;
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            hours[counter] = int.Parse(line);
            counter = counter + 1;
            line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        }
        fileSR.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("hours     pay");
        for (int i = 0; i < hours.Length; i++)
        {
            pay = hours[i] * HOURLY_RATE;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,4} {1,10}", hours[i], pay.ToString("C"));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();




    }
}
```

}

the program needs to display the 20$ in the pay column if it is above 10 hours

Comment: What happens in your while loop if your file has more than 30 lines?

Comment: sorry my bad, typo the file is 30 lines it should be 31, it displays a zero at the bottom of the list, i am also working on it to calculate the average

Comment: That's okay. What I'm trying to get at is it's bad to assume the file will have `x` number of lines all the time: `int[31]`. If your file had 50 lines, you'd get an exception. Instead of an array, use a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to not exceed 20:

```
pay = Math.Min(hours[i] * HOURLY_RATE, MAX_FEE);
```

Comment: okay fixed it works now thanks bro, wish me luck with finding the average having trouble all day, thanks guys :)